# Modifying and rebuilding a Docker image

Tags: docker

I'd like to make a change to a third-party Docker image (the official Shipyard image), and recompose a new image.

Will I have to export a TAR file, expand it into a directory, make the change, build a new TAR, and import that TAR, or is there a way to simply pour the contents of the image into a directory, and rebuild a new one, directly, when done?

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- start from their [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/shipyard/shipyard/blob/master/Dockerfile) or
- just use [`FROM`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#from) [`shipyard/shipyard`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/shipyard/shipyard/) to start your own `Dockerfile` based on their binary image.

Comment: That's fair, but is there a more elegant way to get the Dockerfile or just generally browse the filesystem than having to export the whole thing?

Comment: The Docker Hub will show you the `Dockerfile` for each automated build, but for manual builds you'll need to find their source code repository. There's no guarantee that the Dockerfile is part of the image. **But** if you trust the image, you don't need the Dockerfile. Just use `FROM image` in your own Dockerfile and continue to build on their binary.

Comment: I'm primarily concerned about how to extract or enumerate the files from the image without having to produce an archive of the whole thing and having to extract all of the files for the archive when all I want is just one or a couple.